# Using my django remotely with a ubuntu server

Tags: django, linux

I want to have access to my Django project from anywhere. For this reason, I have a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu.

If I run the command `python manage.py runserver`, it runs the project in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` as default. But this is the localhost of my raspberry/ubuntu and what I want is run the project on my laptop. for this reason I change the `127.0.0.1` for the adress of  my server `http://xxx.xx.xx.x:8000/` and I run it on my browser. **THIS FAILS**.

Ok, reading some information I see that I have to open a port to access remotely, for this goal I use the `ufw` library.

I open the 80 port using `ufw`,

[image]

Now if I write `http://xxx.xx.xx.x:80` on my browser, don't fail, appear this,

[image]

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@djangoproject.localhost
ServerName djangoproject.localhost
ServerAlias www.djangoproject.localhost
DocumentRoot /home/smart/IoTIB_Dashboard
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /static /home/smart/IoTIB_Dashboard/static
<Directory /home/smart/IoTIB_Dashboard/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /static /home/smart/IoTIB_Dashboard/media
<Directory /home/smart/IoTIB_Dashboard/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/smart/IoTIB_Dashboard/IoTIB_Dashboard>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess django_project python-path=/home/smart/IoTIB_Dashboard python-home=/home/user/IoTIB_Dashboard/env
WSGIProcessGroup IoTIB_Dashboard
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/smart/IoTIB_Dashboard/IoTIB_Dashboard/wsgi.py
```

Thus I understand that now is opened.

**The problem** is that if now I run again my django project as `python manage.py runserver 80` and I write again `http://xxx.xx.xx.x:80/user_app/login/` in my browser, appears the following,

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? I'm newbie and I don't know what I have to do. The objective is to be able to access the project remotely. Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/

Comment: can you please share the apache conf

Comment: Where is it? I can't see it

Comment: a lot of unknowns here... If you're going to use runserver then you can turn off Apache (they can't both be on port 80).

Comment: Sorry @danish_wani, I mistake, now is the apache config

Comment: As @TimTisdall said if you are using runserver then you don't need to setup the apache. are you using the runserver?

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing, I just want to see remotely my project xD. I've been following this [tutorial](https://studygyaan.com/django/how-to-setup-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod-wsgi-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I have a ubuntu computer as server with my project and now I want to access to it remotely.

Comment: Best practice is to use a HTTP server like apache/nginx. but for now you disable apache "sudo service apache2 stop" then simply in the directory "python manage.py runserver" and finally you hit the ip like 127.0.0.1:8000 from the browser that's it

Comment: I'm so sorry but I don't understand it, do you know where can I read/watch how to do it? Or if is not to much, can you help me?

Comment: But what this command that are you telling me is to running in the localhost of the same computer, and what I want is run the project remotely